# Suspending training to run evaluation on single GPU in CIFAR-10 tutorial

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to understand the CIFAR-10 tutorial on the Tensorflow website. I can get the training up and running, but I am a little perplexed concerning the evaluation part. It says in [this link](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/deep_cnn#evaluating_a_model) that the evaluation is run periodically, but I can't seem to find anywhere in the code to support this.

How can I implement this so that the training is suspended and evaluation is run periodically, or even better, after a certain number of steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to run `python cifar10_eval.py` at the same time as training for the evaluation to happen periodically (in another terminal for instance). You can choose in the arguments how often you want the evaluation to be run.

However, as stated in the link you're providing, you'll probably need to run it on a different device (ideally another GPU) to avoid memory problem caused by evaluation running at the same time as training.